# Push from an old commit state without creation of new branch

Tags: git, repository

I have come up with a terrible situation, and in general I think I am missing many things in fully understanding git concepts:

We are using git, to share our project between 3 co-workers. 2 of us (A and B) are in the same commit state (our master branch is up to date with origin/master), which happens to be also the latest one, while the 3rd one (C) is in a really old commit state.

In C guy's `git status`, there are "Changes to be committed"(10), Changed but not updated(>40) and Untracked files(12), which **we don't want to lose**. As you can imagine, C guy was not a "pushing fan".

Particularly in our case, the best choice would be to keep all the changes made by C. If I am not mistaken simple push from C's machine would create a new branch

So I was thinking of a way to push all changes from C to origin/master and then A and B guys will pull this commit.

So the question is, what git commands do I need to do this?

Comment: C’s status shows that he hasn’t *committed* at all. C needs to commit those changes first before anything can be pushed. And no, pushing does not create a branch, you seem to misunderstand basic Git things here. Please read a tutorial, there is nothing special about your situation at all.

Comment: Are you sure that commit+pushing from C, without pulling first will not create a new branch?

Comment: C won't be able to push `master` until they've pulled and resolved any conflicts. After that, yes, we're sure pushing won't create a new branch.